# To indent subsection titles in Amsart's table of contents without dots?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I checked this question [Table of contents ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51760/table-of-contents-with-indents-and-dots) out. The answer there puts also dots that I do not want. So how do I indent the subsection titles without dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution presented in the linked question adds leading dots using `\dotfill`. If you don't want dots, just change `\dotfill` into `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima
      \ifcase #1
       \or\or \hskip 1em \or \hskip 2em \else \hskip 3em \fi%
      #6\nobreak\relax
    \hfill\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par% <---- \dotfill -> \hfill
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]